# Is every cocompact lattice in Sp(n,1) residually finite?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

We know that every finitely generated linear group over a commutative ring is a residually finite group by Mal'cev's theorem, but each cocompact lattice in Sp(n,1) is a finitely generated linear group over quaternion which is not a commutative ring. Thus How to verify whether each cocompact lattice in Sp(n,1) is a residually finite group?

Comment: The symplectic group embeds in a general linear group (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: $M_n(\mathbf{H})$ embeds into $M_{4n}(\mathbf{R})$ as a unital subalgebra.

Comment: Ok, I see, it is natural. Thank you very much! However, I also have another question: is there a concrete example of hyperbolic group that we do not know if it is residually finite group?

Comment: @JianguoZhang Possibly among approximations of Burnside groups.

Comment: @YCor Ok, thank you very much again!

Comment: @JianguoZhang: Take a uniform lattice in $Sp(n,1)$, and kill a large power of an element. The quotient will be $\delta$-hyperbolic and non-linear (since lattices in $Sp(n,1)$ satisfy superrigidity by Corlette /Gromov-Schoen), but we do not know if they are residually finite. Explicit presentations of non-uniform quaternionic hyperbolic lattices are given here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06691 Killing a large enough normal finite-index subgroup of the cusp group will also yield a non-linear hyperbolic group that is not known to be residually finite.

Comment: @IanAgol: It is fascinating, thanks a lot!

Comment: There are quite a lot of other concrete examples where residual finiteness is unknown. For instance, there is Caprace's example of a hyperbolic group with property (T): arxiv.org/abs/1708.09772 . Until very recently, you could also cite Kangaslampi--Vdovina's much smaller examples (IJAC, 2010), but my student Calum Ashcroft recently cubulated them (in preparation)...

Comment: (cont'd)... Caprace--Conder--Kaluba--Witzel have recently developed a census of 252 small presentations of generalised triangle groups, many of which have property (T). Residual finiteness is open for most of these. Hopefully their preprint will be posted to the arXiv soon...

Comment: (cont'd)... My initial presumption was that these examples would be smaller than @IanAgol's suggestion, but looking at Mark--Paupert, the presentation for $PU(2,1,O_3)$ is surprisingly reasonable, so maybe Dehn filling its cusps will give some of the smallest examples after all!

Comment: @HJRW: Thank you very much for letting me know that.